# RSS Reader not returning feed

Tags: objective-c, ios4, rss, feedburner

So I'm making a very simple RSS reader for the iPhone, but when I launch it none of the items appear with the feed that I'm using. It works with others, but not with feeds.feedburner/ParadiseBeats
Does feedburner use a different system than other feeds? The feed I first used was technobuffalo.com/feeds which display the stories in rows fine.

Here is the relevant code:

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
if ([stories count] == 0) {
    NSString *path = @"http://feeds.feedburner.com/ParadiseBeats";
    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
}
}
```

and the element parsing...

```
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *__strong)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *__strong)attributeDict {

currentElement = [elementName copy];
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]){
    //clear out story item caches...
    item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

}

}

 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *__strong)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *__strong)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *__strong)qName {

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:currentLink forKey:@"link"];
    [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"summary"];
    [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"date"];

    [stories addObject:[item copy]];
    NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentTitle);
}


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The feed you mentioned may have different attributes for it's rss which are eventually not parsed with the mentioned code.

I had the same problem with other feeds as well although some feeds just work fine.